# how to include a single bar symbol "|" to my regex

Tags: c++, regex

i have found a regex which  can test if the user has entered  ".(cpp)"  or ".(txt)" or ".(5ft6)"

str is the test string and ext is the regex.

```
std::string str("\"\\.(cpp)\"");

const std::string regex_string = R"!(\"\\\.\([[:alpha:][:digit:]]*\)\")!";
const std::regex ext(regex_string);
if (regex_match(str, ext))
{
cout << "regex" << endl; 
}
```

however i am not able to figure out how to make regex for an expression with a vertical bar or the OR symbol "|"

i mean when the user enters the expresion  ".(cpp|h|hpp)" in command line args

there must be a regex for that that specifies that the user can enter any number or letter including the single bar "|"

Comment: Are there any inputs you want to _not_ match? From what you're describing, you may not need to validate this input at all.

Comment: It seems you just want to add a `|` into the bracket expression, `[[:alpha:][:digit:]|]*`, see [this demo](https://ideone.com/WlC5nn).

Comment: Are you sure about the raw string literal syntax there?